# Core Data and a content manager

Tags: ios, core-data

First time working with Core Data en its .xcdatamodeld 
I am using a contentManager for a notes app.
But I am difficulties creating standerd notes.

Is a contentManager normally used for core data? My Problem is where the ?? is.

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: ?? ) as! Note
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly clear what the issue is, but it looks like you simply need to replace `??` with `managedObjectContext`. But, this code should be in a function, not just as variable definitions in the class itself. If you did want to make them variables then you can make them lazy so they're populated on demand the first time they're used.

As for your content manager, I'm guessing you mean some kind of data controller. That's generally a matter of personal preference and how long you've been developing. Generally you want to move the context ownership and management out of the app delegate as that's an inappropriate place to have it and using a data controller for that is clearly better.

Comment: I tried that but got the error that it can't be used on a the content manager (is an NSObject).

Comment: what content manager? post the actual error text, copy and paste it. show also how the context is defined in the app delegate

Comment: added an image as illustration